# WP - Adding Custom Rewrite Rule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to add a custom rewrite rule for my WP site so http://example.com/?u=sample-output, is rewritten as http://example.com/sample-output.

The rewrite rule I'm trying to add is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?u=$1 [L]
```

The existing rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

When I add it in, it gives me a 404 error when I visit the page. I'm guessing this is because of a conflict. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The WP rules rewrites everything to index.php and now you are basically trying to do the same thing with the new rule. You can't do both. Is it one query string that you are trying to rewrite or what?

Comment: @PanamaJack The goal is to rewrite the query string to example.com/query-string. Maybe we can change the WP settings so that other pages go to example.com/pages/?

Comment: Is it all query strings or just that one?

Comment: @PanamaJack Just that one

Comment: There is really no way to tell whether you want to rewrite to query string or to WP rules. So You might need to put WP in a subfolder.

Comment: Any way to rewrite to query string and to modify WP rules to make it work?

Comment: Not that I can see, how would apache know the difference between `http://example.com/somename` and `http://example.com/blogpost`. It sounds like you have 2 different sites. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish using the first rule.

Comment: The string is used on the WP site as well. I'm fine with the string pointing to a different directory, i.e. example.com/start/query-string. Not sure if that will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, put the rule above the WP rules and then you can do something like this. And all URLs that will go to the query string would have to use `/start/` in it. Then make sure to ignore `/start/` in the WP rules like below for all others.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^start/([^/]+)/?$ /?u=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/start [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: When I added this in, it redirects me from example.com/start/query-string to example.com/query-string which shouldn't be happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any other rules in your htaccess file besides that?

Comment: No, that's all there is